# BARRA DE HERRAMIENTAS EN REPORTING SERVICES

Tags: ssrs

Estimados he implementado un reporte en reporting services utilizando SQL Server Business Intelligence Development Studio y la barra del visor me figura una serie de controles como los del archivo adjunto(primera imagen), pero cuando lo quiero ver en la web, alguno de estos no se visualizan(Segunda imagen).
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]